# Dynamic allocation of an int

Tags: c++, dynamic

i'm trying to do a small exercise and i have some problems trying to figure out how to allocate space for an int value in a class constructor. I know it is useless and not recommended but this is the way i have to do it. I know this is a question which has been asked before and it should be a simple task but I couldn't find an answer to my problem so, I'm sorry for the repost. I only kept the part of the code which is not working.  The simplified version looks like this:

```
class AAA{
int *var;
AAA(int *v){
    this->var = new int;
    this->var = v;
}  };
void main(){ AAA a(15); }
```

Thank you for your time and again, I'm sorry for the repost.

Thank you all for your answers ! I haven't forgot the destructor but just kept the code simple in here;thanks again.really helped

Comment: Don't forget what happens if you copy your class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want should be

```
class AAA{
    int *var;
    AAA(int v){
        this->var = new int;
        *this->var = v;
    }
};
int main(){ AAA a(15); return 0; }
```

Don't forget destructor.

Comment: Why not `var = new int(v)`

Comment: Just to mimic OP's intention.

Comment: and don't forget the rest of the rule-of-5.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `int` by value into the constructor, then you can either allocate a new `int` with the argument `v`, or allocate the space first then dereference and assign the value.

```
AAA(int v){
    var = new int(v);
}
```

Note that you now need to define your destructor so you don't leak memory

```
~AAA()
{
    delete var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides some other flaws you should fix your code like this

```
class AAA{
    int *var;
    AAA(int v) { // << no pointer here
         var = new int(v);
    }  
};

int main() { 
    AAA a(15); 
}
```

Note `void main()` isn't valid.

Also note, you should deallocate the memory properly using a destructor

```
~AAA () {
    delete var;
}
```